# While making this random password generator, using the python library random_word, the "random word" in the elif statement sometimes returns "None"

Tags: python-3.x, if-statement, random

```
import numpy as np
from random_word import RandomWords
r = RandomWords()

promptInput = str(input("Do you want to enter your on prompt or randomly generate it, answer 
in yes or no : "))

if promptInput == "yes" :
    passwordHint = str(input("Enter a prompt for making the password : "))
    nums = np.random.randint(1000, 9999)
    newHint = passwordHint.capitalize()
    nums = str(nums)

    password = newHint + nums
    print(password)

elif promptInput == "no" :
    randomWord = str(r.get_random_word(minLength = 5,maxLength = 7))
    nums = np.random.randint(1000, 9999)
    newRandomWord = randomWord.capitalize() 
    nums = str(nums)

    password2 = newRandomWord + nums
    print(password2)
```

> printing this is mostly returning "None" and then the random numbers,
> for example - None8797

```
else :
    print("Enter yes or no only")
```

> This could also be a problem as I previously wanted to test if the
> code would work, so I typed out in the elif statement print("none")

Comment: The Diceware site has a useful word list, though it contains more than just words: [Word List](https://theworld.com/~reinhold/diceware.wordlist.asc).

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're using this module:

> https://pypi.org/project/Random-Word/

If you take a look at its source code, you'll notice that it fetches random words from an online service at api.wordnik.com. If you're trying to generate secure passwords, this is an absolutely terrible idea.

To make matters worse, the service will only respond when provided with a valid API key. The module has three embedded API keys:

```yaml
---
API_KEY: 
 - "d146825 .......... (redacted)  .......... 92d3230"
 - "1eirq2g .......... (redacted)  .......... w02zyj7"
 - "c23b746 .......... (redacted)  .......... b9b658e"
```

I tried using one of these, and got the following response:

```json
{"message":"API rate limit exceeded"}
```

This is probably what's causing the null responses. I suggest you stop using this module immediately and find a better solution.